# Unique Filter, Highest Value

Tags: excel

I would like to take this list in Excel and make it a unique list with no duplicates. I also want the single remaining entry for each food to be the highest value:

```
Crab            1600
Mackerel        1600
Beef            1600
Beef            1600
Beef            1600
Beef            1600
Beef            1600
Chicken         1600
Cod (fish)      1600
Cod (fish)      1600
Split Peas      1500
Lobster         1500
Lobster         1500
White Beans     1500
Lobster         1500
Liver, Chicken  1500
Liver, Beef     1500
Beef            1500
Beef            1500
Turbot (fish)   1500
Shrimp          1500
Tuna (fish)     1500
```

will become:

```
Crab            1600
Mackerel        1600
Beef            1600
Chicken         1600
Cod (fish)      1600
Split Peas      1500
Lobster         1500
White Beans     1500
Lobster         1500
Liver, Chicken  1500
Liver, Beef     1500
Turbot (fish)   1500
Shrimp          1500
Tuna (fish)     1500
```

Comment: It's not clear where those values fall in cells.  Is it possible for you to make a screenshot of your spreadsheet so you know what we're working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to take this list in Excel and make it a unique list with no duplicates. I also want the single remaining entry for each food to be the highest value.

1. Apply a filter to the data and sort descending on the numbers column
2. Select the sorted data and go to the tab `Data > Remove Duplicates`, checkbox only the column that contains the names (in example it would be column A)